# How to tell GCC to generate 16-bit code for real mode

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-16, inline-assembly

I am writing real mode function, which should be normal function with stackframes and so, but it should use %sp instead of %esp. Is there some way to do it?

Comment: What OS is is supposed to run under? GCC doesn't support MS-DOS.

Comment: Here is a minimal runnable example that prints hello world with the BIOS in 16-bit mode from C: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/tree/b4e4c124a3c3c329dcf09a5697237ed3b216a318#c-hello-world

Answer (score 9):

GCC 5.2.0 (and possible earlier versions) support 16-bit code generation with the `-m16` flag. However, the code will almost certainly rely on 32-bit processor features (such as 32-bit wide registers), so you should check the generated assembly carefully.

From the `man` pages:

> The -m16 option is the same as -m32, except for that it outputs the
>   ".code16gcc" assembly directive at the beginning of the assembly output
>   so that the binary can run in 16-bit mode.

Comment: But don't forget what Michael Petch mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055647/how-to-tell-gcc-to-generate-16-bit-code-for-real-mode#comment53870969_19064127 that this only uses the 16 bit prefix versions of instructions, not the bare 16 code.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, gcc could build 16bit code, because the linux kernel is go through realmode to protectmode, so it could even build 16bit c code.  
Then, -m16 option is supported by GCC >= 4.9 and clang >= 3.5
gcc will ignore asm(".code16"),you can see it by -S output the assembly code surround by #APP #NO_APP
the linux kernel do the trick to compile 16bit c with a code16gcc.h(only have .code16gcc) pass to gcc compile params directly.
see [Build 16-bit code with -m16 where possible](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/llvmlinux/2014-January/000820.html), also see the linux kernel build [Makefile](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.16/arch/x86/Makefile#L31)

if you direct put the asm(".code16gcc"), see [Writing 16-bit Code](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002d16bit.html), it's not real 16bit code, `call`, `ret`, `enter`, `leave`, `push`, `pop`, `pusha`, `popa`, `pushf`, and `popf` instructions default to 32-bit size

Answer (score 6):

GCC does not produce 8086 code. The GNU AS directive `.code16gcc` can be used to assemble the output of GCC to run in a 16-bit mode, put `asm(".code16gcc")` at the start of your C source, your program will be limited to 64Kibytes.

On modern GCC versions you can pass the `-m16` argument to `gcc` which will produce code to run in a 16-bit mode. It still requires a 386 or later.

Comment: Documented at: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002d16bit.html#i386_002d16bit

Comment: Using .code16gcc (I'm still not sure one can call it a stable feature) will produce code that runs in 16 bit real mode, however it uses an instruction prefix that is only available on 386+ . This means if you are targeting 8086/8088 (real hardware or emulator) then the code will likely fail to work properly. If you intend to bootstrap entry into 32-bit protected mode then write a small 16-bit assembler stub that sets everything up, enters protected mode and then calls to a 32 bit "C" function that is the start of your program.

Comment: You can of course hand code 16-bit assembler in GCC as inline assembly using __asm__ directive.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, GCC does not support generation of code for 16-bit x86. For legacy bootloaders and similar purposes, you should write a small stub in assembly language to put the cpu in 32-bit mode and pass off execution to 32-bit code. For other purposes you really shouldn't be writing 16-bit code.

Comment: Would you please explain much more. What about -m16 option?