# How does the `asm()` function works in C language?

Tags: gcc, assembly, operating-system, kernel, bootloader

I am learning Operating System Development and a Beginner of course. I would like to build my system in real mode environment which is a 16  bit environment using C language.

In C, I used a function `asm()` to convert the codes to 16 bit as follows:

```
asm(".code16")
```

which in GCC's language to generate 16 bit executables(not exactly though).

**Question:**

Suppose I have two header files `head1.h` and `head2.h` and a `main.c` file. The contents of `main.c` file are as follows:

```
asm(".code16");
#include<head1.h>
#include<head2.h>
int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

Now, Since I started my code with the command to generate 16 bit executable file and then included `head1.h` and `head2.h`, will I need to do the same in all header files that I am to create? (or) Is it sufficient to add the line `asm(".code16");` once?

OS: Ubuntu

Compiler: Gnu CC

Comment: I recommend you not use gcc to compile 16 bit code. What you use is a kludge that causes a bunch of problems.

Comment: [`asm` is not a function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html#Basic-Asm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question: It suffices for the `asm` block to be present at the beginning of the translation unit.
So putting it once at the beginning will do.

But you can do better: you can avoid it altogether and use [the `-m16` command line option (available from 5.2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33022889/5801661) instead.

But you can do better: you can avoid it altogether.

---

The effect of `-m16` and `.code16` is to make 32-bit code executable in real mode, it is *not* to produce real mode code.

Look

*16.c*

```
int main()
{
   return 4;
}
```

Extracting the raw *.text* segment

```
>gcc -c -m16 16.c
>objcopy -j .text -O binary 16.o 16.bin
>ndisasm 16.bin
```

we get

```
00000000  6655              push ebp
00000002  6689E5            mov ebp,esp
00000005  6683E4F0          and esp,byte -0x10
00000009  66E800000000      call dword 0xf
0000000F  66B804000000      mov eax,0x4
00000015  66C9              o32 leave
00000017  66C3              o32 ret
```

Which is just 32-bit code filled with operand size prefixes.
[On a real pre-386 machine this won't work as the 66h opcode is UD](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002d16bit.html#i386_002d16bit).

---

There are old 16-bit compilers, like [Turbo C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Turbo_C)<sup>1</sup>, that address the problematic of the real-mode applications properly.

[image: Turbo C code generation options]

Alternatively, switch in protected mode as soon as possible or consider using UEFI.

---

<sup>1</sup> It is available online. This compiler is as old as me!

Comment: ["Don't Mention the War!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfl6Lu3xQW0). The fewer people that know about Turbo-C(++) the better!

Answer (score 0):

It is not needed to add `asm("code16")` neither in `head1.h` nor `head2.h`.

The main reason is how the C pre-compiler works. It replaces the content of `head1.h` and `head2.h` within `main.c`.

Please check [How `#include' Works](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC7) for further information.

Hope it helps!

Best regards,

Miguel Ángel