# Is there a way to convert C++ code to Intel 8086 Assembly and get .asm file?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-16, masm

Is there a way to convert C++ code to Intel 8086 Assembly and get .asm file? I'm trying to figure out how to do it, GCC wouldn't work. Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: gcc -S <filename>

Comment: @SeanF: Not for an 8086, though.

Comment: @SeanF Technically even with [`-m16`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) the `gcc` assembler code is not guaranteed to run on pre-80386 processors, such as the 8086, see some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055647/how-to-tell-gcc-to-generate-16-bit-code-for-real-mode) for example.

Comment: You need an 8086 C++ compiler.  There are some C compilers discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493035/is-there-a-c-compiler-that-targets-the-8086 and some of them had C++ compilers also.  Note that since they target an obsolete machine, it is also likely that they only run on similarly obsolete machines, and that they only support obsolete versions of the C++ standard.

Comment: @NateEldredge `ia16-gcc`?  Or some other compiler, like Open Watcom?

Comment: Unfortunately, most MS-DOS compilers (including Watcom version 10.6) directly compile to object code and do not output assembly code.