A question regarding an ISO - building a simple operating system
I'm working on a simple operating system, written mainly in c++ and a bit of assembly. In reality, my operating system is actually an ISO image that I load into an Oracle virtual machine.
Before going into the details of the question I will add that I'm writing a real mode operating system and am currently writing and testing an IVT (Interrupt Vector Table). As far as I understood this IVT needs to be loaded in the RAM from address 0x0 to address 0x3FF - stretching 1024 bytes (the table has 256 entries with each entry being 4 bytes in size).
I will also add that my operating system follows the monolithic kernel design and therefore my code consists of many different source files that are compiled individually and then linked together to form one big kernel file. In addition, I'm using the GRUB menu as my bootloader.
My problem is as following: since I want the IVT to be loaded into a specific place in memory I also want it to be the first section of my linked kernel file. Here is the current state of my linker script:
ENTRY(loader)
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:i386)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x000000;

    .ivt : /* Define a section for the IVT */
    {
        /* Place the IVT here */
        *(.ivt)
    }


    . = 0x100000;
    .text :
    {
        *(.multiboot)
        *(.text*)
        *(.rdata)

    }

    .data :
    {
        start_ctors = .;
        KEEP(*( .init_array));
        KEEP(*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY( .init_array.*)));
        end_ctors = .;

        *(.data)
    }

    .bss :
    {
        *(.bss)
    }

    /DISCARD/ :
    {
        *(.fini_array*)
        *(.comment)

    }
}

As you can see, I placed the .ivt section to be at the beginning of the linked file. To clarify, here is what the .ivt section looks like in the source code:
void (*IVT[256])() __attribute__((section(".ivt")));

As you can see, it's an array with 256 elements, with each being a void pointer to a function.
In addition, I define the multiboot header for the GRUB menu in an assembly file the following way:
.set MAGIC, 0x1badb002
.set FLAGS, (1<<0 | 1<<1)
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS)

.section .multiboot
    .long MAGIC
    .long FLAGS
    .long CHECKSUM

The error I get is as following (screenshot added):

From what I see there, the GRUB doesn't even recognize that a multiboot structure exists and therefore doesn't even load the kernel.
Any ideas (regarding both the IVT and also what happens with the linker script) will be greatly appreciated. Thank you all :)
Expected the linked file to properly be loaded by the GRUB menu and for the code inside to be executed. Rather, I infer the GRUB didn't even recognize the linked file as a valid kernel file and therefore didn't load it.

You don't want to load the IVT to its location anyway. Your code should copy it at runtime. Also make sure your linking does not accidentally include a ton of padding which moves the multiboot header outside of the allowed range. PS: do you have a C++ compiler that outputs real mode code? How can your .text be at 0x100000 which is almost outside of real mode address space? How do you initialize the IVT with proper segment offset?

You can copy a whole IVT if you wish but you should do that at runtime and not have it loaded there directly. You said you were writing a real mode OS, so just wanted to clarify that you have a compiler that outputs suitable code. Most importantly memory addressing.

@Jester You mean by that my registers sizes need to be 16 bit for example? How do I achieve this? by using compilation flags? Also, do you see any problem with the current state of the outputted linked file? I can't really figure why it isn't even acknoledged as a kernel file. Is it because of the way I load the IVT somehow?

As I said, during linking you might end up with padding which moves the header out of the allowed range. You can access 32 bit registers in real mode with a prefix (if your cpu supports it). As to whether there are any flags you can use depends on your C++ compiler.

@Jester I'm using the gcc compiler, along with a few compilation flags that restrict the use of a few libraries

I don't think gcc is really usable as a 16-bit real-mode compiler. You can get it to emit code that will run in real mode, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055647/how-to-tell-gcc-to-generate-16-bit-code-for-real-mode, but it's really 32-bit code and won't run on anything less than a 386.

So if you really want to keep pretending you're in the 1980s and write 16-bit code, then you will probably need to dig up a compiler from that era (and maybe some parachute pants too).  If you want to join the world of 2024, then have your bootloader switch to long mode, and compile your C++ into 64-bit code.  Interrupt handling is completely different in that world (using an interrupt descriptor table instead of the IVT in low memory).

@NateEldredge Open Watcom 2.0 work reasonably well and there of course is the ia16-gcc port of GCC (it is still rough around the edges.

I have a small multiboot project here that doesn't copy data/code from >= 0x100000 to 0x0000 but I do copy it to 0x1000 in low memory (you can do the same for 0x0000). I have a linker script and in kernel.c I have some code that does the copy. Multiboot compliant bootloaders put you in 32-bit protected mode. Do you have code that drops back to real mode? My project is here: https://github.com/marleyd386/OSDev/blob/master/examples/v8086-intn-iret/kernel.c
